# list comprehension not obeying if statement

Tags: python

This stub of my program

```
with open(fi) as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    lines = [line.split('!')[0] for line in lines if not line.startswith('!') and line.strip()] # Removing line and inline comments
    for line in lines:
        print line, len(line), bool(not line.startswith('!') and line.strip())
```

gives me output such as

```
conduction-guess                        double_array    optional    68 True
valence                                 character       optional    68 True
valence-guess                           double_array    optional    68 True
                                                                    68 False
saturated-bond-length-factor            double          required    68 True
```

Shouldn't the line whose bool value is False not be included? I'm lost.
I thought it might be short-circuiting, but flipping the expression doesn't help either.

To clarify, I want my list to be a list of the lines that end with 'True' in the above section of code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first `not line.startswith('!') and line.strip()` is operating on a different set of `line` values than the second one.  The list comprehension causes `lines` to be replaced with a list of the first `!`-delimited field of each string in the original value of `lines`, and it is this new `lines` that the code then prints out.  For example, if `lines` originally contains the string `" !foo"`, this string will pass the conditional in the comprehension, but only the part before the `!` — a single space — will be saved into the new `lines` list, and a single space will not cause `line.strip()` to return true.

Answer (score 2):

You could see something like that if you had a line in your file which had an exclamation point somewhere other than in the first column.  e.g.:

```
line = " !                    "
```

Comment: That is in fact what is happening, but the reason why eluded me.

Comment: Oh, I see. The comprehension is turning the above line into pure whitespace which would then be interpreted by the print statements as a false, but its already too late and the list has been made.

Answer (score 0):

`line.strip()` returns a new string, it's not a boolean.

Updated code:

```
with open(fi) as f:
    lines = [ line.strip() for line in f ]
    # remove exclamation points
    lines = [ line.split('!')[0] for line in lines 
              if not line.startswith('!') 
              ]

    # 3rd col will always be True
    for line in lines:
        print line, len(line), bool(not line.startswith('!'))
```

Comment: what if it returns an empty string?

Comment: if `line` is an empty string or whitespace, then yes `line.strip()` will be treated as `False`. In practice, when reading from files, all lines except maybe the last one have newlines.  When `not line` is true, that means you've reached the end of the file.